# Get a label and Image same spot Apple Watch App

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, watch

I am implementing a countdown label in the center of the apple watch, and I would like to get images in the center once countdown is = 0 (same spot as the countdown).

Is it possible to have the label an image in the same spot? I know I can hide the label once time = 0 but how can I place the image in the center as well.

Any ideas would help!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to see the image when the countdown label is 0 and if you want to see image and the label together you can change the image's alpha
if it is true the solution is like this;

```
image.setHidden(true)
if countDown == 0 {

image.setHidden(false)

}
```